# How to properly set up drush 9.7.0 on Windows 10

Tags: drush

I am working on trying to set up and learn drush for the first time on a Drupal 8.7.3 site on Aqui DevDesktop which i installed with composer. This is the first time I have tired composer, and drush is **completely** new to me. (I was really impressed with the efficiency of composer with installing modules BTW... I am a complete noob to this stuff and it was rather easy)

To get drush I followed the directions provided at: https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ and ran:

```
composer require drush/drush
```

which gave me drush 9.7.0

I am able to get the command line to recognize drush status from **any directory**:

```
drush status 

Drupal version : 8.7.3
Site URI       : http://default
PHP binary     : C:\xampp\php\php.exe
PHP config     : C:\xampp\php\php.ini
PHP OS         : WINNT
Drush script  :C:\Users\user\Sites\devdesktop\drupalup_comp\vendor\drush\drush\drush
Drush version  : 9.7.0
Drush temp     : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp
Drush configs  :
C:/Users/user/Sites/devdesktop/drupalup_comp/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
C:/Users/user/Sites/devdesktop/drupalup_comp/drush/drush.yml
Drupal root    : C:\Users\user\Sites\devdesktop\drupalup_comp/web
Site path      : sites/default
```

The trouble I am having is the command line doesn't want to recognize commands relative to the site itself. The documentations says that drush should be run from:

```
vendor/bin/drush
```

but there is no drush directory **folder**  just the file and application within the bin directory. (maybe that's my problem?)

For example when i run:

```
C:\Users\user\Sites\devdesktop\drupalup_comp\vendor\bin> drush en migrate_tools
```

I get:

```
"Command pm:enable was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. 
As a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with -- 
debug to see relevant log messages."
```

I have run the --debug, but was not smart enough to make heads or tails of it :). I am way over my head here, so I hope I have provided enough info for this to make sense. From the little bit I have gathered this could be a path issue? Any pointers would be much appreciated!

PS:
Composer installs modules like butter so quit crying about it and get with the times. If I can do it, you can too!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Config Your Settings.php
You have not a database, or run your mysql service

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => '',
  'username' => '',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

And run Drush in your "Drupal root"

```
C:\Users\user\Sites\devdesktop\drupalup_comp/web

../vendor/bin/drush status
```